# Pass variable from #each loop to helper emberjs

Tags: javascript, loops, ember.js, handlebars.js, each

I'm having problems passing template variables into helpers, i got a template like that

`{{#each row in workpage.mainStructure}}
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='cell cell-2'>{{i18nForecasts row.value }}</div>
          {{#each cell in row.amounts}}
            <div class='cell'>{{cell.format}}</div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}`

and my helpers only needs to log the passing val:

```
 Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('i18nForecasts', function(property, options) {   
   var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(property);
  console.log(escaped);
});
```

The thing is that i only get the value as 'row' in string and not the looping values. but if i try to print the value with out the helper like:

```
{{row.value}}
```

It prints the correct loop value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `registerBoundHelper`, http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('i18nForecasts', function(property, options) {   
   var escaped = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(property);
   console.log(escaped);
});
```